# Writing feature class attributes and counts to Excel workbook in Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, excel

I have a feature class with 3 fields that I would like to reference later in an excel workbook.  They are all represented in 3 different maps.  I would like to show the the attribute counts for these 3 fields in Excel.  The purpose of this is to ultimatelly create an automated process with Adobe Indesign for map book creation.

The ideal process would be:

1. Select feature class attribute to be shown on map.
2. Python automation to show the number of features displayed on map, written to text file or excel workbook.
3. I don't want every column or row written, only the attribute displayed in layout or data view in ArcGIS.
4. I would like to complete this from the Python window in ArcGIS for QA/QC purposes.

Comment: Can you describe the desired output a little more, preferably with an example of both the input and the output?

Comment: Are you just trying to get counts of unique values in a particular field from a featureclass?  If so, I think you could just use the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) or [Frequency](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001w000000) tools and write the results out to Excel using [Table To Excel](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000054000000).

Comment: The ultimate output should show the count of each attribute shown on a map, akin to the show feature count option within the legend.  The summary statistics tool does not meet the needs of this process.  As when it is executed it shows the total count, not count of each category.  For instance, if there are 5 As 5 Bs 10 Cs 15 Ds, I would like to print the parsed attribute fields and the count to excel rows.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using? I ask because the export to Excel is easier at 10.2.

Comment: Why not using summary statistics as suggested by @RyanDalton ? It does count the number of As, Bs or Cs in a field. Otherwise, i you want to do it with your own code, you could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437727/python-write-to-excel-spreadsheet for writing in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I think the key question here is how to get a count of how many features are within the current map extent into a Python variable. To do this I would use the extent to create a geometry that you can pass into SelectLayerByLocation and then GetCount. I recommend you focus this Question on that Answer-able aspect, then research/ask about any other blockages in your workflow separately.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: Geoffrey, the "Case Field" option in Summary Statistics should give you what you are after, unless as @PolyGeo stated, you are looking for just the results within the visible frame.

Comment: Geoffrey, take a look at the XLWT and XLRD python modules - these are built for reading and writing into Excel files.  I have used them in the past to produce Excel reports of my data.

Comment: @dklassen thank you, would I be able to write from pythonwin and the arcpy module into previous workbooks with specific formatting?

Comment: @GeoffreyWest it's those kinds of "little" requirements that should be stated up front (and edited into the question instead of snuck into the comments). I believe `xlwt` will let you do this but most of the other options mentioned here so far will not. Though looking a little bit into InDesign scripting I do not see why Excel is needed at all, so perhaps you could explain why it is important to use it as opposed to some other format.

Comment: The Indesign script references an excel workbook with specific formatting.

Comment: @GeoffreyWest, Yes, I believe those modules will let you add data to existing Excel documents.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management()` and `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()` to select the features you want.  Then use: 
`arcpy.GetCount_management` tool to get a count of the selected objects.  Using XLRD you can write to excel or just use:

```
outfile = open('OUT_TEXT_FILE.txt','w')
outfile.write("write the first line here" + "\n")
outfile.write("write the second line here" + "\n")
..
..
outfile.write("write the nth line here" + "\n")
outfile.close()
```

This will write to a new txt file - be careful - if the text file already exists - it will overwrite - to append use 'a' instead of the 'w' in the open command.